# How to check if a string is in and cellarray?

Tags: matlab

I have a cellarray with a list of strings:

```
my_cell_array = {'stringA', 'stringB', 'stringC'}
```

Is there any efficient one-liner to check if a literal string is included in the cellarray?

Something like python:

```
if 'stringC' in my_cell_array
```

Answer (score 2):

Just found the answer myself:

```
ismember('stringC', my_cell_array)
```

Comment: Also: `any(strcmp('stringC', my_cell_array))`